# pip freeze | could not find svn URL in dependency_links

Tags: svn

I get this error when I  run pip freeze:

```
Warning: cannot find svn location for apsw==3.7.17-r1
...
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
apsw==3.7.17-r1
```

What does this mean? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-part problem.

Firstly the error is [a known bug in pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/287). It seems to mean that one of the packages (`apsw` here) was installed directly from a subversion repository but that the reference to it (so that it can be recreated) wasn't stored properly so it can't be referenced properly in a freeze-list.

To half-explain and half-compound that issue `apsw` isn't available <strike>in the shops</strike> on pypi. [Its modern documentation](http://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/download.html#easy-install-pip-pypi) says as much:

> APSW is not available at the Python Package Index (pypi) and hence cannot be installed using easy_install, pip or similar tools.

I'm personally not sure if I agree with that. Pip has been able to do checkout-based installations for a while. Here's a real example one I have:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/danirus/django-pagedown.git@b67da0a5c68c8f1d75922afe7f5dc8eac3172a0b#egg=django_pagedown-dev
```

You might be able to bend that format to your will with something like this:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw.git@8e09f8aec2b759cf7de3532490505f71c60c74da#egg=apsw
```

Who knows. Play around. Oh and you might need to remove it manually first.